# how to set dynamic radio value in state

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component in which i have questions state and showing question inside the render function and trying to change the submit_answer state on onchange of radio event.

```
import React from 'react';
class Question extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            questions:{
                1:{
                    question:"What is html full fomr",
                    options:{
                        a:"hyper text model language",
                        b:"hyper text markup language"
                    },
                    answer:"a",
                    submit:"not",
                    submited_answer:""
                },
                2:{
                    question:"this is question two",
                    options:{
                        a:"hyper text markup language",
                        b:"hyper text model language"
                    },
                    answer:"b",
                    submit:"not",
                    submited_answer:""
                },
                3:{
                    question:"this is question three",
                    options:{
                        a:"hyper text markup language",
                        b:"hyper text model language"
                    },
                    answer:"b",
                    submit:"not",
                    submited_answer:""
                },
                4:{
                    question:"this is question four",
                    options:{
                        a:"hyper text markup language",
                        b:"hyper text model language"
                    },
                    answer:"b",
                    submit:"not",
                    submited_answer:""
                }
            },
        }
        this.changeAnswer=this.changeAnswer.bind(this)
    }
    changeAnswer=(question_id,value)=>{
        let objectState=this.state.questions[question_id].submited_answer
        this.setState({objectState:value},()=>{
            alert(objectState)
        })
    }
    render(){
        let question_id=this.props.question;
        let object=this.state.questions;
        let changeAnswer=this.changeAnswer
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>{object[question_id].question}</h2>
                {Object.keys(object[question_id].options).map(function(key) {
                    return <div><input type='radio' onChange={()=>changeAnswer(question_id,object[question_id].options[key])} name='answer' value={key} />{object[question_id].options[key]}</div>;
                })}
                {object[question_id].submited_answer}
                hello world
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Question;
```

My change answer is still showing null. I am getting 1 in this.props.question. And is there any other easy way to do this

Comment: For getting selected value do this : In changeAnswer function user alert(this.state.objectState) instead of alert(objectState) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating your object correctly.Update you changeAnswer function as follow

```
    changeAnswer=(question_id,value)=>{
     let objectState=this.state.questions;
     objectState[question_id].submited_answer = value;
     this.setState({objectState},()=>{
        alert(this.state.objectState)
      })
    }
```